# MS Word Insert > Pictures (from Ribbon) Stopped Working

Tags: vba, ms-word

In MS Word (2016) I am trying to insert an image (usually a trivial thing) using the insert tab on the ribbon.  I click the Pictures button expecting a browse dialogue to appear but nothing happens.

On a side note, the VBA `application.Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture).Show` also fails to produce the insert picture dialogue.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Properties]

EITHER of these settings prevent users from adding images

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look when I can next access the PC in question :)